# Can one use "in the same vein" as an adverbial connector that means "in this regard" or "Also", ...?

Tags: idioms-in-context

Suppose a self-made paragraph as

> The university decided to offer a mix of in person and on line courses for the fall. **In this vein**, the university has announced that students should wear masks in common spaces and there would be penalties if they do not abide by the rules.

I am wondering if it is idiomatic to use "in this vein" in such contexts?  I mean, I know that I can use words and phrases like "also", "in addition", ... etc, but for the sake of variety, I want to know if it is fine to use "in this vein" as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend if you live in Britain or in North America. In my research of "in this vein" I didn't find reference to other English-speaking lands.

From [UsingEnglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/in+that+vein.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20do%20something%20in,same%20distinctive%20manner%20or%20style.), which seems to be a British site:

> If you do something in that (or this) vein, you do it in the same
> distinctive manner or style.

From [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=In%20that%20vein)

> Talking/Thinking along the lines. Talking/Thinking about the same or
> similar topic
>
> In that vein, what do you think about the health reform?
>
> The prime minister was talking about the austerity measures in the
> recession times. The opposition party also went on in that vein.

From [Washington State University](https://brians.wsu.edu/2016/05/16/along-the-same-vein/):

> The expressions “in the same vein” and “along the same line” mean the
> same thing (“on the same subject”)

If you are in the United States, it should therefore be fine to say it the way you are saying it. One could easily substitute "In this vein" with "On the same subject." However, in your sentence it would not seem right to me to say "along the same line" because wearing masks and being in class is not "along the same line." However, both regard the subject of the fall semester. That is how I analyze it. Others may have other opinions. I offer several definitions so you can choose the one that seems most appropriate for your personal situation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I was talking about the US.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use in this vein. Style-wise, it makes the sentence awkward and pedantic. Reword the paragraph. Here is a better version:

...for the fall. It has announced that students ( student is
incorrect because singular nouns need a 'qualifier' such as ' the' ) with in-person courses should wear masks...abide by the rules. (or, if you prefer - 'adhere to the rules ')

Postcript: Some verbs require specific prepositions. Examples: abide by, adhere to, look for (if searching for something), look at ( if being instructed to view something) etc.